# Firebase: how to delete users from multiple nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I have a situation where my database is structured like this:

```
{  
   a:{  
      key1:user1_UID,
      key2:user2_UID,
      key3:user3_UID
   },
   b:{  
      key1:user1_UID,
      key2:user3_UID
   },
   c:{  
      key1:user1_UID,
      key2:user3_UID
   }
}
```

and I want to delete `user1_UID` from all the nodes `a, b, c` when any of the `user1_UID`'s are deleted.

For example if I delete `key1:user1_UID` from node `b` is there a way to also delete `key1:user1_UID` from node `a` and node`c`, without iterating through all the nodes? Or am I structuring my data wrongly (note that these may be more deeply nested)?

Comment: which language do you use?

Answer (score 1):

if you know the path to the all nodes, then  you can use Update command to delete all of them, correct me if i am wrong.

```
var updateData = {};

updateData["a/key1"] = null;
updateData["b/key1"] = null;
updateData["c/key1"] = null;

firebase.database().ref().update(updateData, function(error)
{
  if(error)
  {
   //error goes here
  }
}
```